# Attention line in letters

Tags: business-language

Is "To the attention of" a correct phrase  to be used instead of "Attn:" in the attention line of a business letter?

Comment: What did your research show, and why do you distrust it?

Comment: There is no single right or wrong way to set up a business letter; there are certain conventions, but these vary by locale. That said, how to use an attention line is not really a question about English, as there is some equivalent of it in many languages, originally to simplify the delivery of mail in very large organizations or in very large buildings.

Comment: I have always thought 'To the attention of' to be a correct phrase until today. I am non-native speaker translator and I have stared a full time job where I have a mentor for the initial 6 months. My mentor is not an native English speaker too. Today she told me 'it was not English' to say 'To the attention of' and I was surprised. That is why I was seeking an expert native-speaker opinion.

Comment: "For the attention of" would be better. It even has its own abbreviation, FAO. A [search for *to the attention of*](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=to+the+attention+of) yields lots of help. When asking a question, please use dictionaries and even Google and present the results of your research -- if that research doesn't actually answer the question. The first link in [my search in the UK](https://www.englishforums.com/English/ForAttentionAttentionOf/gzblh/post.htm) may well do that. If none of the results on the first page help, you have a lot of background information to use in hte question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See e.g., http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tcdnstyl-chap?lang=eng&lettr=chapsect10&info0=10.16 which implies that this is a matter of style.  If you don't like "Attn:" because it seems too abrupt/shorthand, perhaps use "Attention:".  Using "To the attention of" is not very businesslike, because in business brevity and directness are valued.